# Wrap html/css/js in a webkit executable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I'm looking to make an executable that will open my web project in a (frameless?) executable, and I'm coming up short on a solution.

The request is simple: I want to be able to package my html/css/js project for distribution. I would like for the renderer to be either webkit or firefox.

Have any of you seen this technology in the wild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) is exactly what you're looking for.

I've been using it (the .net distro) for about a year now with great success.  It also comes in mac and linux flavors.  I'd highly recommend it.  Best part is that its [free for Indies](https://awesomium.com/buy/)! :D

Comment: I would have loved something automated, but I'll take what I can get. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

http://techblog.netflix.com/2010/12/why-we-choose-html5-for-user.html?m=1

Netflix is doing it for PS3 for example.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I don't think it helps accomplish my goal, but it was an interesting read nonetheless.